# Error: The username and password is invalid no secret no next url NextAuth.js

Tags: next.js, next-auth

i know its a bit long but please read through and help a dev like you
Hey everyone permission to post this here so am working currently on a nextjs application currently and am using next auth for signing in users i know about clerk though used in most of my project but this time i thought of working with next auth but after my api set up i keeping getting some funny errors while trying to login in to my web app first when i login with the credentials it takes me to a page of sign in with credentials when i do check my payload from the network i do see all my credentials like email and password but it throws an error when i try to continue from there these are the errors below
on my terminal i get this server response

```
/* ○ Compiling /_error ... ✓ Compiled /_error in 1482ms (1176 modules) ○ Compiling /api/auth/[...nextauth] ... ✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth] in 2.3s (796 modules) [next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret ○ Compiling /_error ... ✓ Compiled /_error in 810ms (1414 modules) [next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret */
```

and on my console network source i get this error
Invalid email or password
but the thing is that this user exist in my database i have registered it so i don't know if its the secret or this invalid error i even created another account and it still throws same errors finally this is the form am using the api

```
/* if (type === "login") {
const res = await signIn("Credentials", {
...data,
redirect: false,
});
if (res.ok) {
toast.success("Account Created Successfully");
router.push("/chats");
}
if (res.error) {
toast.error("Invalid email or password");
} */
```

```
i have tried changing my api route twice and i have even modified my api code but still no avail
```